# rc.local hang on bootup

Tags: rhel, boot, init-script

My `rc.local` is stuck in an infinite loop since I accidentally put a wrong I/O redirection in and it's executing itself over and over again.

I'm on Red Hat 6.5 and would like to know how I can start the machine without the `rc.local` being run so that I may fix the problem? It is also on a virtual machine and not a physical machine with VMware.

Comment: If it wasn't a VM, you could boot with a live disc, mount the hard drive, and then edit the rc.local file. Perhaps there's a similar way to mount VM drives as well.

Comment: yes that is true, however if you know your way around linux using the single user boot is a faster way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot into single user mode by going into the Grub menu and select the kernel version and press e to edit press space and type single

Comment: I was curious, so I looked this up for LILO. It's almost the same: From the LILO boot prompt enter `MyLinux single` where 'MyLinux' is the name LILO uses for your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Besides booting into single user mode you could attach a virtual CD-ROM containing an installation or rescue system image, boot that, mount the root filesystem of the machine and edit the boot scripts. This may be more comfortable to use than using single user mode.